# Multidimensional Array - Illegal String Offset

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that for some reason keeps kicking back an error "Illegal String Offset" I have tried several ways to loop through it but none seem to work.

```
$fields = Array (
[cookies] => Array (
    [timeout] => 0
    [votes_per_cookie] => 1
    [enabled] => on
    )
[ip] => Array (
    [timeout] => 0
    [filter] => 
    )
[direct] =>  Array ( )
[membership] => Array (
    [type] => Array ( )
    [once] =>  Array ( )
    )
[captcha] =>  Array ( )
[quota] => Array (
    [votes] => 1000
    )
[date] => Array (
    [start] => 1553846400
    [end] => 1554767940
    [enabled] => on
    )
[selection] => Array (
    [minimum] => 1
    [maximum] => 1
    )
[unique_id] => 1547834405
[results] => Array (
    [require_vote] => Array (
        [enabled] => on
        )
    )
);
```

I am trying to get the value of `end` in the `date` array. I have tried this:

```
foreach($fields as $field) {
  echo $field['end'];
}
```

this outputs the data but also the illegal offset error.

I have tried this:

```
foreach($fields as $key => $value) {
  echo $value['end'];
}
```

This also outputs the same reponse.

if I echo `key` using the above loop, it returns the appropriate keys (cookies, ip, direct, membership, etc)

I have also tried:

```
foreach($fields['date'] as $field) {
    $field['end'];
  }
```

This is just an error.

And finally

```
foreach($fields as $field) {
  $field['date']['end'];
}
```

just an error.

Comment: try to simple echo without foreach as echo $fields['date']['end'];

Comment: @BalvinderSingh yep....that did it. thanks!

Comment: Great! Welcome @RiotAct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Reason:*** `end` is the key of child array of `date` index (which is an index of parent array), so you have to use `date` also to fetch child-key value

***Solution:***

```
echo $fields['date']['end'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate, just access the fields directly:

```
echo $fields['date']['end'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop the array since you wanna get specific key value:

First method :

```
echo $fields['date']['end'];
```

second method :
 this little bit ugly the method.

```
echo array_column($fields,'end'))[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array should look like this in order to loop through.
I've added quotation strings ("") to your **indexes** and to your **on** value. Else you would get a warning: like this 'Use of undefined constant on'.Hope this helps!.

```
     $fields = array (
      'cookies' => array ('timeout' => 0,'votes_per_cookie' => 1,'enabled' => 'on'),
      'ip'=> array ('timeout' => 0,'filter' => '',),
      'direct' =>  array (),
      'membership' => array ('type' => array (),'once' =>  array ()),
      'captcha' =>  array (),
      'quota' => array ('votes' => 1000,),
      'date' => array ('start' => 1553846400,'end' => 1554767940,'enabled' => 'on',),
      'selection' => array ('minimum' => 1,'maximum' => 1,),
      'unique_id' => 1547834405,
      'results' => array ('require_vote' => array ('enabled' => 'on'))
    );
```

Now you can loop through it properly with a **foreach**:

```
foreach($fields as $key => $value) {
  if($key == 'date'){
    print_r($value);
  }
}
```